# Upgrading to Laravel 5.2 - Index redirect loop Auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-5

I'm currently upgrading one of my projects **from 4.2 to 5.2**.

Yesterday I was at a point where everything was OK in 5.1 so I started the **5.2 upgrade**.
Of course, I followed closely all the steps in the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0).

I'm close to get everything to work but I'm totally stuck on a redirect loop caused by the **Authenticate middleware**.

### Here is how I've narrowed it down

After hours of tests and search I've come to a very minimal setup where the bug is still here...

**routes.php** (everything else is commented):

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes non-ressources de l'application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', ['as'=>'index', 'uses'=>'SessionsController@create']);
```

The **SessionsController.php** :

```
<?php

class SessionsController extends \BaseController
{
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
    // dd('toto');
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return Redirect::to('/accueil');
        }
        return View::make('pages.login');
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(Input::only('email', 'password'))) {
            return Redirect::to('/accueil');
        }
        Flash::error(Lang::get('global.login_error'));
        return Redirect::back()->withInput();
    }


    /**
     * Log the user out
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy()
    {
        Session::flush();
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }


}
```

The **kernel.php** middleware declaration:

```
/**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
        'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
        'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
        // 'App\Http\Middleware\AccessMiddleware',
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        // 'auth.canaccess' =>'App\Http\Middleware\AccessMiddleware',
        'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    ];
```

And finally, the Authenticate.php middleware (The basic included in laravel 5.2) :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('/');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

### The redirect loop error I get

While accessing my home page, I get this error: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in chrome. (Same kind of error in the others browsers)

I've get to a point where I know that this specific line in the middleware causes the redirection loop:

```
return redirect()->guest('/');
```

But what I can't figure out is WHY this behaves like that !
- My index route is not supposed to trigger the auth middleware
- My SessionController doesn't use any middleware in it's constructor

Have I missed something in the upgrade process ? What can cause a middleware to trigger other than a declaration in the **routes.php** or in a **controller's constructor** ?

Any help would be very appreciated =)

Comment: Another way is to just put a middleware in $middleware property of your Kernel. Those are middlewares that are executed for all routes. Remove accessmiddleware from there and it won't be applied unless explicitely  enabled.

Comment: Ohh ok I don't remember where my $middleware content comes from (lots of tests since the bug came out), but indeed I recovered the kernel.php from the laravel github and it works now ! Thanks a lot ! =)